# SQL- LOAD DATA INFILE + REPLACE doesn't work (row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

Here is the score_table looks like.

```
Number | Name | Score | Parent
```

1. The primary key is Number+Name (Composite Key).
2. Import .csv files.
3. The `Name` column is set by web controller .
4. In table already exists data:

`Number | Name | Score | Parent
1         MJ      85    Micheal
2         Katie   60    Jay`

Now I want to use `load data infile` and `replace` to modify data into table.

(.csv is `1  MJ   100   Micheal`)

(which means replace MJ's score with 100)

SO I write the SQL as belows :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE scores.csv 
REPLACE INTO TABLE score_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(Number,Score,Parent)
SET Name = #{name}
```

But comes the error:
*row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns*

How to solve this? Thanks!

PS:
Maybe should let you know that
I tried writing the SQL statement without `REPLACE`.(others are the same)
It worked (no compiling error) but CANNOT change the score from 85 to 100.

Comment: "row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns" suggests that there are problems with the data, you're trying to load, don't you think? Show us some sample data, including the first row.

Comment: I think it's not the problem with data because I removed REPLACE and it worked (just without replace)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File: `/path/to/file/scores.csv`

```bash
1,MJ,100,Micheal
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `score_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `score_table` (
    ->   `Number` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Score` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `Parent` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`Number`, `Name`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `score_table`
    ->   (`Name`, `Score`, `Parent`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('MJ', 85, 'Micheal'),
    ->   ('Katie', 60, 'Jay');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Number`,
    ->   `Name`,
    ->   `Score`,
    ->   `Parent`
    -> FROM
    ->   `score_table`;
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
| Number | Name  | Score | Parent  |
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
|      1 | MJ    |    85 | Micheal |
|      2 | Katie |    60 | Jay     |
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/scores.csv'
    -> REPLACE INTO TABLE `score_table`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (`Number`, @`Name`, `Score`, `Parent`)
    -> SET `Name` = @`Name`;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 1  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Number`,
    ->   `Name`,
    ->   `Score`,
    ->   `Parent`
    -> FROM
    ->   `score_table`;
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
| Number | Name  | Score | Parent  |
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
|      1 | MJ    |   100 | Micheal |
|      2 | Katie |    60 | Jay     |
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```